# AVCaptureDevice.requestAccess not working in iOS10 XCode 8

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3, ios10, xcode8

I'm trying to follow the tutorial to create a barcode scanner. https://www.appcoda.com/simple-barcode-reader-app-swift

I have added the "***Privacy - Camera Usage Description***" key to the Info.plist. But I still get the following error:

```
2016-10-03 21:32:44.345156 project[10017:2678833] [MC] System group container for systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles path is /private/var/containers/Shared/SystemGroup/systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles

2016-10-03 21:32:44.349956 project[10017:2678833] [MC] Reading from public effective user settings.
```

Has anyone been able to work around this?